# Computing area below 2D function

Tags: plotting, special-functions, regions

I'm trying to find an area (in `η` and `y` plane) in which the below function is >=0

```
-1. η ((-5. + y) MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 0.}, {-1.}}, y^2] 
+ (10. - 2. y) MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 0.}, {-1.}}, 4. y^2]
+ 2. MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 1.}, {-1.}}, y^2]
- 4. MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 1.}, {-1.}}, 4. y^2])
```

Why doesn't `RegionPlot` doesn't work?

The code is:

`RegionPlot[-1. η ((-5. + y) MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 0.}, {-1.}}, y^2] 
 + (10. - 2. y) MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 0.}, {-1.}}, 4. y^2]
 + 2. MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 1.}, {-1.}}, y^2]
 - 4. MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 1.}, {-1.}}, 4. y^2])>0,{y,0,5},{η,0,0.01}]`

Comment: What is the full code here...?

Comment: Immediately I can see that this might not work because when y=0, this is undefined and an error occurs. You say it "doesn't work", what exactly is going wrong for you?

Comment: It takes a long time and then the kernel quits

Answer (score 3):

The required area can be calculated as follows.

```
NIntegrate[ Boole[-1. \[Eta] ((-5. + y) MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 0.}, {-1.}}, 
    y^2] + (10. - 2. y) MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 0.}, {-1.}}, 
    4. y^2] + 2. MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 1.}, {-1.}}, y^2] - 
  4. MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 1.}, {-1.}}, 4. y^2]) > 0], {y,0,5}, {\[Eta], 0, 0.01}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
```

> 0.0197613

Here is a picture

[image]
created by

```
Plot3D[{-1.*\[Eta]*((-5. + y) MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 0.}, {-1.}},
    y^2] + (10. - 2. y) MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 0.}, {-1.}}, 
   4. y^2] + 2. MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 1.}, {-1.}}, y^2] - 
 4. MeijerG[{{-0.5}, {}}, {{0., 1.}, {-1.}}, 4. y^2]), 0}, {y, 0, 5}, {\[Eta], 0, 0.01}]
```